# How do I auto-increment a unique version number using ActiveRecord?

Tags: ruby, activerecord, auto-increment

I have a model `License` that needs to have a version number (an `Integer`) but I don't want that to be confused at all with the actual `id`.

I have a field `version_number`.  What is the *simplest* way to tell ActiveRecord to automatically increment it on creation?

Comment: How thread-safe does this need to be?  We've found that with multiple Rails processes running over multiple servers, the only way to generate truly unique version numbers was to delegate the generation to an external service; in our case using a Postgres sequence.

Comment: Not very in the this case.  Licenses won't be updated a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a `before_create` callback to set `version_number` to the last version + 1:

```
class License < ActiveRecord::Base
  before_create :set_version
  ...
  def set_version
    license = License.last
    current_version = license.nil? ? 0 : license.version_number
    self.version_number = current_version + 1
  end
  ...
end
```

Comment: To get the next version you could also do `self.version_number = ( License.maximum(:version_number) || 0 ) + 1`

Comment: Thanks Adam and nice one Danne.  That does exactly what I am after.